# Message from deep negative space

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, cipher

```
A_MS

_IDE_IDE_IDE_IDE_IDE

BE_TBE_TBE_T

BE_SBE_S

A_MSA_MS

S_AREDS_AREDS_AREDS_ARED

BEA_

_IDE_IDE_IDE

BE_TBE_TBE_TBE_T

BEA_

PE_KPE_KPE_K

_AST_AST

BEA_BEA_BEA_BEA_

A_MSA_MS

_ONS_ONS_ONS_ONS

T_ET_E

_IGHT_IGHT_IGHT_IGHT_IGHT_IGHT

A_MS

S_AREDS_ARED

BE_TBE_TBE_TBE_T

WA_ES

POL_POL_POL_
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let us

> fill in the blanks to create the following words:
>
> ```
>  AIMS
>
>  SIDE AIDE WIDE TIDE HIDE
>
>  BEET BEAT BENT
>
>  BEGS BEES
>
>  ALMS AIMS
>
>  SNARED STARED SHARED SEARED
>
>  BEAM
>
>  AIDE RIDE BIDE
>
>  BELT BEET BEAT BENT
>
>  BEAD
>
>  PECK PEAK PERK
>
>  VAST EAST
>
>  BEAD BEAU BEAN BEAT
>
>  AIMS ALMS
>
>  IONS SONS EONS TONS
>
>  THE TIE
>
>  MIGHT FIGHT RIGHT EIGHT EIGHT MIGHT
>
>  AIMS
>
>  SCARED SHARED
>
>  BEET BELT BEAT BENT
>
>  WAGES
>
>  POLE POLL POLO
> ```

giving us the quote

> **"I saw the angel in the marble and carved until I set him free." - Michelangelo**

Comment: how did you come to putting the letters on each line in a correct order?

Comment: Joining to htmlcoderexe: and how did you come up with having to use the same solution for each singular "A_MS" but a different one for each singular "BEA_"?

Comment: @htmlcoderexe and zovits — I will be curious to hear user39583's answer, but the way I envisioned someone solving it would be:   first, make a list of all the letters that *could* fit in the blanks, and then rearrange the letters to see what words begin to emerge.

Comment: @SlowMagic That's pretty much it, although it seemed quite impossible to start from the beginning so I had to start by spotting the Michelangelo at the end and then recognizing the quote.